# Parse API update object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I'm having a problem Parse. I am using JavaScript (Angular and Bootstrap3) to build a small application.

I have hit a problem now though, I am trying to add an array of dates to existing`Events` objects and save the new dates to the Parse backend, however no matter what I try, I seem to always have `undefined` when I look in the object browser.

#### My JavaScript code:

```
    console.log("setSuggestedDate");
    console.log(conEvent.selectedEvent.newDate);
    //get existing dates
    //convert this date to JS date Sring
    //check if new date is in existing dates
    //add new date to existing dates or +1 the count of the existing new date
    //update the object server-side
    //trigger new getEvents()
    var dates = conEvent.selectedEvent.dates;
    console.log(dates);
    var nDate = new Date(conEvent.selectedEvent.newDate);
    var date = nDate.valueOf().toString();
    console.log(date);
    if(dates){
        if(dates[date]){
            
            dates[date].count++;
            
        }else{
            
            dates[date] = {
                "count": 1,
                "suggestedBy": Parse.User.current()
            }
            
        }
    }else{ //No Dates
        
        dates = {}
        dates[date] = {
            "count": 1,
            "suggestedBy": Parse.User.current() 
        }
        
    }
    console.log(dates);
    var eEvent = Parse.Object.extend("Event");
    var query = new Parse.Query(eEvent);
    console.log(conEvent.selectedEvent.id);
    query.get(conEvent.selectedEvent.id, {
        success: function(e) {
            console.log("success");
            eEvent.set("dates", dates);
            eEvent.save();
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            // The object was not retrieved successfully.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        }
    });
```

I've determined that all the variables work as they should and when I get to `var eEvent = ....` the date is a new date object (the first else statement in the code).

I have tried following [this guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-updating-objects) but to no success.

An example of conEvent.selectedEvent (copied from the console):

```
$$hashKey: "object:6"
creator: ParseUser
dates: undefined
description: "just a test"
id: "F0QEbvwqLK"
name: "test"
newDate: Wed Dec 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: what is the data that you are using?

Comment: using where specifically?.... Vague questions... I'm not good with vague questions lol

Comment: conEvent.selectedEvent?

Comment: I'll update the question with that

Comment: Look at the bottom of the question

Comment: If it helps, i just realised that the query is throwing an error after making a request 0.o